JavaFx Music Player
I built a small program that searches and plays wav files on your PC.
This Java Music Player application is my first comprehensive project. It features a straightforward graphical user interface (GUI) for playing music files on your PC.
It is really basic, but I hope that I can get constructive criticism here.
Link: https://github.com/TboyBell/JavaMusicPlayerGit.git
Code:
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Player {
    
    static JFrame frame;
    private static Clip clip;
    private static boolean isPaused;
    private static boolean isLooping;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        frame = new JFrame("Music-Player");
        frame.setSize(600,150);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                exitApp();
            }
        });
        
        Font font = new Font("Franklin Gothic Medium",Font.ITALIC,15);
        
        JTextField display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setFont(font);
        display.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        display.setBounds(15, 25, 300, 25);
        frame.add(display);
        
        
        JButton chooseFile = new JButton("Choose");
        chooseFile.setFocusable(false);
        chooseFile.setFont(font);
        chooseFile.setBounds(320, 25, 100, 30);
        chooseFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Wav Files", "wav");
                    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                    int userAction = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                    if (userAction == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION && selectedFile != null) {
                        display.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No File Selected");
                        display.setText("No File Selected");
                    }
                }
            });
            frame.add(chooseFile);
            
        
        JButton play = new JButton("Play"); 
        play.setFocusable(false);
        play.setBounds(430, 25, 100, 30);
    
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                playMusic();
            }

            
            private void playMusic() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                if(clip != null && clip.isRunning()) {
                    clip.stop();
                }
                
                try
                {
                    File file = new File(display.getText());
                    AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                    
                    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(audio);
                    
                    if(isLooping) {
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);                  
                        }
                    
                    clip.start();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found: " + e.getMessage() + ". Please use the Choose button to select a file.");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                
            }
            
        });
        frame.add(play);
        
        
        
        JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
        pause.setFocusable(false);
        pause.setBounds(320, 70, 100, 30);
        pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pauseMusic();
            }

            private void pauseMusic() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                    if(clip != null && clip.isRunning()) {
                        clip.stop();
                        isPaused = true;
                        pause.setText("Resume");
                    }
                    else if(clip != null && isPaused) {
                    
                        clip.start();
                        
                        if(isLooping) {
                            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    isPaused = false;
                    pause.setText("Pause");
                }           
        });
        frame.add(pause);
        
        
        JButton loop = new JButton("Loop");
        loop.setFocusable(false);
        loop.setBounds(430, 70, 100, 30);
        loop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loopMusic();
            }

            private void loopMusic() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
                try {
                isLooping =  !isLooping;
                if(isLooping) {
                    loop.setText("UnLoop");
                    
                    if(clip.isRunning()) {
                        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                    }
                    
                }
                else {
                    loop.setText("Loop");
                    if(clip.isRunning()) {
                        clip.loop(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found: " + e.getMessage() + ". Please use the Choose button to select a file.");
            }
            }
            
            
        });
        frame.add(loop);
        
        
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    

    public static void exitApp() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.dispose();
        
    }




    
    
    
}


You use the JavaFX tag. I can't see anything in your code that's related to JavaFX.

Noice monolith
In software development we strongly aim for independent components. That is because software is always in development progress - and changes can be made easier on independent isolated components.
The opposite of independent components is creating a big piece of code that contains everything, a so called monolith (the proper antipattern name is Big ball of mud or God Object). This is bad because that makes changes much harder.
Beginners tip: MVC
Try to apply the (old & well described) MVC pattern (Model View Control), splitting your code into a

model: contains the Clip and functionality to play/pause/repeat/load/etc - the model should be totally independent from any other components (view/controller)
view: the swing gui you already created - all input from gui goes to the controller
controller: input listener, that delegates input from gui (buttons) to the model (and also brings back information from the model to the gui)

That would really bring your code to the next level - and is super easy to learn for beginners! (Note:
Code quality
The code you wrote is easy to understand. That is very good. A good starting point for a refactoring into MVC
Follow up

I would be very glad to see how you split up the code into a MVC and read your follow up code-review
There are some other issues, that will hopefully disappear, once the code is split up. But these are to be discussed after the MVC split
There are other approaches to MVC (MVVC, HMVC) but i think as beginner, stick with the basic


Thanks, I will do that.
